# Error Code: 1064 on constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
create table boat
    (bid integer not null constraint c_bid primary key,
     bname varchar(40),
     color varchar(40) 
     constraint c_color check (color in ('Red','Blue','Light Green','Yellow')));
```

I use this sql code on a script using mysql workbench and the word contraint is red and with the error Syntax error : unexpected 'constraint' (constraint).

When i run the script i get:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'color_c constraint check (color in ('Red','Blue','Light Green','Yellow')))' at line 5  0.000 sec
```

Comment: MySQL currently does not support check constraints.

Comment: The syntax error is because you left out the comma at the end of the `color` line. But MySQL will ignore the `check` line -- the only kind of constraint it supports is `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: ^^ This is [documented with the CREATE TABLE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) _"The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines"_